# Apache POI Mixed word format not working properly

Tags: java, apache-poi

FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fileInputStream);

```
        for (XWPFParagraph p : document.getParagraphs()) {
            Boolean isPrg=true;
            XmlCursor cursor = p.getCTP().newCursor();
            cursor.selectPath(
                    "declare namespace w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' .//*/w:txbxContent/w:p/w:r");

            List<XmlObject> ctrsintxtbx = new ArrayList<XmlObject>();
            while (cursor.hasNextSelection()) {
                cursor.toNextSelection();
                XmlObject obj = cursor.getObject();
                ctrsintxtbx.add(obj);
            }
            for (XmlObject obj : ctrsintxtbx) {
                
                CTR ctr = CTR.Factory.parse(obj.newInputStream());
                XWPFRun bufferrun = new XWPFRun(ctr, (IRunBody) p);
                String text = bufferrun.getText(0);
                
                if (text != null && text != "") {
                    isPrg= false;
                text = text.replace("[RECEPIENT_NAME]", name).replace("[ADDRESS1]", address1).replace("LETTER_GEN_DT", date)
                        .replace("[ID]",sbsbid).replace("MEMR_RX_ID", memrid)
                            .replace("MEMR_MCTR_RX_GROUP", memrgroup).replace("MEMR_MCTR_RXBIN", memrrxbin)
                            .replace("MEMR_MCTR_PCN", memrpcn);

                    
                    System.out.println("header line is "+ text);
                    
                    if((address2 == null || address2.equals("")) && (address3 == null || address3.equals(""))) {
                        text = text.replace("[ADDRESS2]",city+", "+state+" "+zip).replace("[ADDRESS3]","").replace("[ZIP]", "").replace("[CITY]", "").replace("[STATE]", "");
                        }
                        else if((address2 != null && !address2.equals("")) && (address3 == null || address3.equals(""))) {
                        text = text.replace("[ADDRESS2]",address2).replace("[ADDRESS3]",city+", "+state+" "+zip).replace("[ZIP]", "").replace("[CITY]", "").replace("[STATE]", "");
                        }
                        else if((address2 == null || address2.equals("")) && (address3 != null && !address3.equals(""))) {
                        text = text.replace("[ADDRESS2]",address3).replace("[ADDRESS3]",city+", "+state+" "+zip).replace("[ZIP]", "").replace("[CITY]", "").replace("[STATE]", "");
                        }
                        else if((address2 != null && !address2.equals("")) && (address3 != null && !address3.equals(""))) {
                        text = text.replace("[ADDRESS2]",address2).replace("[ADDRESS3]",address3).replace("[ZIP]",zip).replace("[CITY]", city).replace("[STATE]", state);
                        }
                    
                    bufferrun.setText(text,0);
                    
                }
                obj.set(bufferrun.getCTR());
            }
            
            if(isPrg) {
                String runTxt="";
                p.getCTP().documentProperties();
                for(int i = 0; i < p.getRuns().size(); i++)
                {
                runTxt=runTxt+ p.getRuns().get(i);
                }
                System.out.println("main footer is :"+runTxt);
                
                runTxt=runTxt.replace("[RECEPIENT_NAME]", name).replace("[PDP_NAME]", pdpname)
                        .replace("[ENRL_EFF_DT]", enrolldate).replace("[GLBL_PHONE_NUMBER]", phoneNumber);
            
                
                int psize= p.getRuns().size();
                if(psize>1) {

                for(int i = 0; i < psize-1; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        p.removeRun(psize - i - 1);
                        
    
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                }
                for(XWPFRun ffr:p.getRuns()) {
                    ffr.setText(runTxt,0);
                break;
                }
                }
                    
            
        }
        outFilePath = filePath.replace(".docx", "_convert.docx");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                new File(outFilePath));
        document.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Output.docx written successully");
    
    } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("We had an error while reading the Word Doc");
    }
    return outFilePath;
}
```

Input Text :

will **automatically terminate** without notice when the base Contract terminates for any reason

Output i am getting like this:

will automatically terminate without notice when the base Contract terminates for any reason

For output also i need Bold text format after replacing the words in documents

Expected Output is :

will **automatically terminate** without notice when the base Contract terminates for any reason

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using apache-poi for updating word documents. the word document contains Bold and Normal font. when I update the document updated document doesnt have bold text . instead of that bold text coming as normal font @Community

Comment: Your code is not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That's why it is not possible to tell exactly what your code does wrong.  But your code removes `XWPFRun`s and the text-formatting is only contained in `XWPFRun`s. So that will be the problem. Try another approach for search and replace text. Use `TextSegment` for example. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a3915431%20textsegment for examples.